# Pass params to react function with autobinding :: operator

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, ecmascript-next

How do you pass params to a react function when using the auto binding `::` syntax?

```
<span onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 'hi')} />
```

If I want to use auto binding `::` in a function without params I change it as follows:

```
<span onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)} />

<span onClick={::this.handleClick} />
```

Comment: is there a reason you don't do `onClick={() => this.handleClick('hi')}`. Definitely more efficient than binding

Comment: @azium I feel like this would be most efficient `onClick={::this.handleClick('hi')}` however I am not sure if it is valid.

Comment: it would be less efficient because that's just sugar for `bind`

Comment: `::` is an experimental feature. It is not part of ES6. And I guess the answer is: You can't. https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator

Comment: thanks @FelixKling I guess not, but it would be nice.

Comment: thanks @azium Did you have some more information on why its more efficient, out of interest?

Comment: arrow is just referencing `this` where `.bind` has to do work, which you can get a sense of by the polyfill [from the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind)

Comment: [babel repl](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20T%20%7B%0A%20%20m()%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20r()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20onClick%3D%7B()%20%3D%3E%20this.m()%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cdiv%20onClick%3D%7Bthis.m.bind(this)%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using babel you can add stage-1 to your .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1", "react"]
  // the rest of your config
}
```

And then in your component you can create methods like this:

```
onUpload = () => { ... }
```

that will be binding automatically :D

Comment: it is also experimental.